# Center the gallerz and put the h1 above it

Tags: center

Hey I'm new to this html and css world. I want to create a website about events but I don't know how can center everything.
Could someone help me please?
I want the h1 be on top of the gallery like the pic I draw.

```
https://imgur.com/f3P3V1A
```

`https://imgur.com/StJioAQ`

```
https://imgur.com/NQ0XL8n
```

Comment: Hi there! Can you make the images links?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for flexbox. You can find a good tutorial from CSS Tricks (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). In particular, I think you're reaching for the "justify-content: center" and "align-items: center" properties.